# PDO Registration Form

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm struggling to get to grasps with PDO from mysql, here is my registration form.

The error I'm receiving isn't quite making sense to me, can anyone help me complete my registration form?

```
<? include 'includes/overall/head.php'; 
include 'core/init.php';?>
<div id="page" class="container">
<div id="box1">
    <h2 class="title"><? echo $welcome; ?></h2>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="entry"> 
        <form method="POST" action="process_user.php">
        Username*: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
        Password*: <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
        Confirm Password*: <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirm" /><br/>
        Email*: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
        Confirm Email*: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="email_confirm" /><br/>
        <?require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $publickey = "*****";
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<? include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

This is the prcess_user.php

```
<? include 'includes/overall/head.php'; 
include 'core/init.php';?>
 <div id="page" class="container">
<div id="box1">
    <h2 class="title"><? echo $welcome; ?></h2>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="entry"> 
        <?
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $privatekey = "*****";
          $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

          if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and     try it again.");
          } else {  

        if (empty($_POST) === false) {
            $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'email', 'email_confirm');
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
                if (empty($value) && in_array($key,    $required_fields) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are    required.';
                break 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (empty($errors) === true) {
                if(user_exists($_POST['username'] === true)) {
                    $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username   \''.$_POST['username'].'\' is already taken.';
                }
                if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username'] ==   true)) {
                    $errors[] = 'Your username cannot contain    any spaces';
                }
                if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6 ||   strlen($_POST['password'] > 32)) {
                    $errors[] = 'Your password must be between    6 and 32 characters';
                }
                if ($_POST['password'] !==     $_POST['password_confirm']) {
                    $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match';
                }
                if (filter_var($_POST['email'],     FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                }   
                if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
                    $errors[] = 'The email address     \''.$_POST['email'].'\' is arealdy registered.';
                }                   
            }                   
        }
        if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
            echo 'You\'ve been successfully registered, please check     your email inbox to activate your account';
        } else {
            if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                $register_data = array(
                    'username' => $_POST['username'],
                    'password' => $_POST['password'],
                    'email' => $_POST['email'],
                    'email_code' => md5($_POST['username'] +          microtime())
                );
                register_user($register_data);
                header('location: register.php?success');
                exit();
            } else if(empty($errors) === false) {
                echo output_errors($errors);
            }

            //LINK TO GO BACK AND TRY AGAIN
        }

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<? include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

And finally, the functions to go with them

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
$username = sanitize($username);
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = `$username`";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
return ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) ? true : false;
}
function email_exists($email) {
$email = sanitize($email);
$query = "SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = $email";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
return ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) ? true : false;
}
function register_user($register_data) {
array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
$register_datapw = $register_data['password'];
require ('../../includes/blowfish.class.php');
$bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
$register_data['password'] = $bcrypt->hash($_POST['password']);

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

$query = "INSERT INTO `USERS` ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();   
}
?>
```

This is the error I receive

`[08-May-2013 09:44:52 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$' in .../process_user.php on line 50` Which is
`if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {`

Comment: this error has nothing to do with PDO nor with form processing. it's PHP syntax issue. You need to learn proper PHP syntax first

Comment: `echo $query;` in `register_user`, it ll maybe make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `empty()` function in PHP has some really weird semantics. Per [the fine manual](http://php.net/empty):

> Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`.

Similarly, you will need to use `$_GET['success'] == false` instead of `empty($_GET['success'])`.

---

As an aside: You are using PDO, which is good, but you are still interpolating user input into your SQL queries, which is very, very, very bad. Learn how to use PDO correctly with bound variables before you proceed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, I'll be sure to check that out.